# accept header in ajax that returns [HTTP_ACCEPT]=>*/*

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ajax

I need to get the accept header as image/webp but instead I get only */*.

How to do it in Ajax request? It happens in Ajax page only please some one help me to do it in Ajax PHP.

My Ajax code is

```
function showResult(str){
    if (str == '') {
      $('#clear').hide();
    }else{
      $('#clear').show();
      $.ajax({
      url: "<?=tep_href_link('ajax_search.php') ?>",
      type: 'POST',
      data:{type:'adavnced_search',str:str},
      success:function(result){
        $("#livesearch").html(result);
        var numItems = $('.p_remove').length;

           $('#livesearch').slideDown('fast',function(){
          $('#overlay').css({'display' : 'block'});
        }); 
      }
    });
    }
  }
```

Please help to get the required accept format as image/webp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the required content type in "Accept" under "headers":

```
function showResult(str){
    if (str == '') {
      $('#clear').hide();
    }else{
      $('#clear').show();
      $.ajax({
      url: "<?=tep_href_link('ajax_search.php') ?>",
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {          
          Accept: "Image/webp"
      },
      data:{type:'adavnced_search',str:str},
      success:function(result){
        $("#livesearch").html(result);
        var numItems = $('.p_remove').length;

           $('#livesearch').slideDown('fast',function(){
          $('#overlay').css({'display' : 'block'});
        }); 
      }
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks this works fine ..could u pls let me know the use of this webp

Comment: @pukka lol you asked for the header to be webp, we might have assumed you knew what it was. It's an image format, just like jpg or png. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP

Comment: what if the browser does not support the webp? since here in your code you have mentioned it as even if the browser does not support webp accept the header as webp. so what is the solution for this?

Comment: so i need like this if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'webp') --> show

Comment: @pukka, you should post the follow up questions separately. That said, like all questions on this site, they should be able to stand on their own, come with sufficient explanation what is needed, how it works, how it *should* work and what has been attempted.